# How to read from a text file in C++?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to read a bunch of strings from a text file and saving the characters in a 2D array. The following is my code:

```
char** fileReader(char* fileName){
    ifstream treeFile;
    treeFile.open(fileName);
    string line;

    vector<string> fileContents;
    int rows=0, columns=0;


    while (getline(treeFile, line )){
        fileContents.push_back(line);
        rows++;
    }

    columns = fileContents.at(0).length();

    char** fileContentsArr;
    fileContentsArr = new char*[rows];

    for (int x=0; x <  rows; x++){
        fileContentsArr[x] = new char[columns];
        for (int y=0; y < columns; y++){
            fileContentsArr[x][y]= fileContents.at(x)[y];
        }
    }

    treeFile.close();
    return fileContentsArr;
}
```

Output should be:

```
TTTTTTTT
TTTTTTTT
TTTTFFFT
TTTTTTFF
FFFFTTFF
FFFFTTFF
FFFFTTTT
FFFFTTTF
```

But instead I am getting only the first 7 characters from each line and only the first 7 strings.

Actual output:

```
TTTTTTT
TTTTTTT
TTTTFFF
TTTTTTF
FFFFTTF
FFFFTTF
FFFFTTT
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you posted does not output anything

Comment: How is your printing code going to know the size of the 2D array you've created?

Comment: You use iostreams, you even have a `vector<string>`. Why on earth would you return a `char**`? C++ provides the standard library containers and strings for a reason. Use them everywhere you can... return the `vector<string>` directly.

Comment: Needless to say, your function would be much better off returning `vector<string>`, with a `return fileContents;` straight after the `while` loop, and we wouldn't be looking at your bugs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the STL to do almost everything you need here:

```
vector<string> fileReader(char* fileName){
    ifstream treeFile(fileName);

    vector<string> fileContents(
        (std::istream_iterator<string>(treeFile)),
        std::istream_iterator<string>());

    return fileContents;
}
```

This creates the vector using its two-iterator constructor, with the first iterator reading from `treeFile` and producing `string`s.  The second iterator (default-constructed) signifies the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed version:

```
// Changed return type:
std::vector<std::string> fileReader(char* fileName){
  ifstream treeFile;
  treeFile.open(fileName);
  string line;

  std::vector<std::string>  fileContents;
  /// int rows=0, columns=0;

  while (getline(treeFile, line )){
      fileContents.push_back(line);
      rows++;
  }

  // Cut off rest of code, instead:
  return fileContents;
}
```

If you want to access a character, you can use

```
std::vector<std::string> data = fileReader("file.txt");
char value = data[3][2];
```

as intended.